# Expose the user form into a page

Tags: views, forms, users

I've been thinking for a user-friendly navigation into my website.

I wanted to exposed the user form into a page where they can just easily update their information. I've installed the module profile 2 and added 3 types of profile (Personal Data, Withdrawal Form and Drawing Records), these 3 types of form I want to expose in one page.

Can it be just embedded into a views or do I need to use hook_form_alter? Please help... Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you want here. But i think i understood that you have 3 profile types defined in profile2 and want to expose these to anonymous users, so that they can sign up?

If this is indeed the case, then i would reccomend you to take a look at the profile2 registration path module

https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath

This module allows you to setup a direct menu path to a user registration form that shows the profile types you select

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need 3 different profiles? For me it looks like you can have one profile with fields divided to 3 set of different field Groups using [field group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module

With your current approach of having 3 different profiles form on one page might be [multiple forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiform) module will be of some help to you.